# Problems setting up Grafana Agent

Tags: grafana

I was trying to set up Grafana-agent.yml file for nginx but with multiple attempts no success. The setup provides we with an sample configuration and what i have to add to the configuration. This is the example configuration:

```
integrations:
  agent:
    enabled: true
    relabel_configs:
    - action: replace
      source_labels:
      - agent_hostname
      target_label: instance
    metric_relabel_configs:
    - action: keep
      regex: (prometheus_target_.*|prometheus_sd_discovered_targets|agent_build.*|agent_wal_samples_appended_total|process_start_time_seconds)
      source_labels:
      - __name__
  prometheus_remote_write:
  - basic_auth:
      password: <your_prom_pass>
      username: <your_prom_user>
    url: <your_prom_url>
logs:
  configs:
  - clients:
    - basic_auth:
        password: <your_loki_pass>
        username: <your_loki_user>
      url: <your_loki_url>
    name: integrations
    positions:
      filename: /tmp/positions.yaml
    scrape_configs:
    - job_name: integrations/nginx
      static_configs:
      - targets:
        - localhost
        labels:
          host: <http_hostname>
          __path__: <path to json nginx access log>
metrics:
  configs:
  - name: integrations
    remote_write:
    - basic_auth:
        password: <your_prom_pass>
        username: <your_prom_user>
      url: <your_prom_url>
    scrape_configs:
  global:
    scrape_interval: 60s
  wal_directory: /tmp/grafana-agent-wal
```

In this configuration the configuration for nginx is already there. Now what i dont understand is with what information i have to fill out the fields like metrics.config.basic_auth.password or logs.configs.scrape_configs.targets.host

i Already attempted to search for a sample configuration that documents the values better.

Comment: I can give you some help, but in order to elaborate, I would need first to if you are using Grafana Cloud or you are using you own Prometheus instance.
The <your_prom_user> and <your_prom_pass> are the basic auth configured in Prometheus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get started, I would recommend you to login to Grafana Cloud (it's free), and on the left side menu, go to *"Connections", "Add a new connection"*.

There, you can just click on *"Linux"* and you will get a sample config for metrics and logs:

[Node exporter metrics sample config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mnJCn.png)

[Logs sample config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rkeB.png)

This should be enough to have a sample agent communicating with Prometheus and Loki and being able to query data with Prometheus.

You can also use/check [this code repository](https://github.com/spanishkangaroo/grafana-agent-on-premises) (DISCLAIMER: I'm the owner) and in particular, the [agent config file](https://github.com/spanishkangaroo/grafana-agent-on-premises/blob/main/conf/grafana-agent/agent-linux.yaml).